# In the figure, x-axis is considered to be along the incline. The coefficient of friction varies with as $\mu=kx$ where $k=\tan\theta$

Tags: derivatives, physics

> A block is released from O. Find the maximum distance travelled by the block.[image]

Acceleration of the block will be 
$$g\sin\theta(1-x)$$
Velocity can be written as 
$$v^2=u^2+2ax$$
$$v^2=2(g\sin\theta(1-x))x$$

For x to be maximum, velocity needs of be zero.
$$2g\sin\theta(x-x^2)=0$$
$$x=1,x=0$$
But the answer given is 2. What am  I doing wrong.

*NOTE: I know this is more of a physics question, but since my problem mostly lies with the math regarding this question, I posted it here*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an equation of constant acceleration whereas the acceleration you are using is variable. You must use calculus to solve this question.

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=g\sin\theta(1-x)$$

Therefore

$$v\frac{dv}{dx}=g\sin\theta(1-x)$$

Integrating from $0$ to $x$
$$\frac{1}{2}v^2=g\sin\theta(x-\frac{1}{2}x^2).$$

Therefore the velocity is zero when $x=2.$